# best way to pass results of one forkJoin to another via http

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, fork-join

I need to make multiple http calls (angular) and return the results of one forkJoin to another.
the following will not work:

```
Observable.forkJoin([
       this.userService.createAccountHttp(accountRequest),
       this.userService.verifyAccountHttp(res)
 ]);

createAccount() {
  return this._http.jsonp<any[]>('http://...', 'callback').pipe(
      map(v => {
        return v;
      })
}
verifyAccountHttp(res) {
  return this._http.jsonp<any[]>('http://some url/' + res, 'callback').pipe(
      map(v => {
        return v;
      })
}
```

as res is undefined.
Is there a way to use forkJoin to run sequential http calls and pass results of one http call to the next?

Thanks

Comment: Please can you share your request examples

Comment: added to questions, tx

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I have interpreted your question correctly, but the RxJS [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operator might be something you can consider. `switchMap` will allows you to map over the observable values from `createAccountHttp` into the inner observable.

```
this.userService.createAccountHttp(accountRequest)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((res) => this.userService.verifyAccountHttp(res)),
  ).subscribe((res) => {
    // do the rest here
  });
```

Comment: Thanks... there is no way to use forkJoin to run sequential http calls and passing results of one http call to the next?

Comment: @born2net no you can't if u need the response of the first api call to make the second call you need wait for the first response.

Comment: @born2net sadly, no, and this is due to the nature of asynchronous operations on TypeScript/JavaScript. You will need to wait for the observables from `createAccountHttp` to be subscribed/returned, before you can utilise the results from the next set of operation/request. The only time when you can use something like `forkJoin`/`combineLatest` would be when both methods are fired and they do not need to depend on each other.

Comment: I was under the impression that forkJoin was like promiseAll and you can sequence the calls?

Comment: why you doesn't want to use async/await ? if you need to wait until first request end?

Comment: @born2net you are absolutely right! forkJoin is the equivalent of `Promise.all`, for observables. However, in your case, the second request (`verifyAccountHttp`) is dependent on the first request (`createAccountHttp`), thus there is no way you can fire them concurrently. You can only do them in sequence as per the method I suggested above.

Comment: I am trying to keep it pure rxjs with no side effects